# Android Bluetooth: RFCOMM + bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am developing an Android application which would make intense use of Bluetooth RFCOMM connection between two devices, with data streaming using the default `BluetoothAdapter`.

What I am wondering is:

is it possible to use such a connection while the user is listening to music using a Bluetooth headset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a RFCOMM socket to a service record you specify a unique identifier (UUID).  These are unique to each connection and you can have multiple open RFCOMM Bluetooth connections to multiple sources/devices with different UUIDs.  So yes, you should be able to listen to music while having RFCOMM connections sending/receiving data elsewhere.

See methods listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord and createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord on [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) and [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) respectively.